# Adding and changing checkbox names + labels on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I am working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/VkYnQ/

The goal is to select as many times you want, and then select what time, and then it should add and show the times under the `'Copy to more dates?'` .

Currently it has the 1 static checkbox, just to demonstrate how it should work.

So when there's 1 static checkbox 0800 out from each weekdays, it means that you have selected 1 time and that one time is currently at 08:00.

And if you change this time to 16:00, the checkbox name and label should change to 1600.

If select 2 times, and select the second to 20:00, it should add a checkbox at each weekdays next to the other checkboxes, with label "2000"

This is what I have tried, for making the changing work, so the checkbox follow if you change from e.g 08:00 to 16:00 like mentioned above: http://jsfiddle.net/epCbv/1/

Which is working, but I cant figure out a way to make it work with my code.

Hope anyone out there can help me out, I'll reward with an +300 reputation/bounty, when it's possible (2 days).

Comment: When you say 'select 2 times', you're talking about the 'Select times:' drop down? When I first read your question, I thought you might have meant a multi-selection on the 'Time:' dropdown in one of the red boxed areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not aim to do all the job but I updated your code to make it approaching the goal you are looking for. The code is dirty, I do not spend a lot of time but it remains understandable.

Let me know if this is really on the good way :)

See the result: http://jsfiddle.net/adrieng/VkYnQ/3/

Nota Bene: The update stuff is not linked to the first `select.timeclock`. So chose, for example, to display at least 2 times and change the time on the second, third, fourth,… select input ^^

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! You are on the right way, and as you said the first select.timeclock does not work. If you could make it work for the first one ::  and do so when you go from 4 times to 2 times, it removes the related checkboxes :: and so the name="" attributes for the checkboxes are correct, like the first example copyTime[the random number][1800] that would be great , i will reward you +300 for all the effort

Comment: The improvement you asked for are there: [http://jsfiddle.net/VkYnQ/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/VkYnQ/6/). The change of the first `select` do not work on fiddle but works locally.

Comment: If the first select work outside the jsfiddle then great! Now only one thing left is that the checkboxes should have names: copyTime[THE WEEKDAY][TIMECLOCK] , Sunday has weekday 1 , monday 2 etc up to saturday 7 . Then the TIMECLOCK should be the one the checkbox is showing . This is the only thing left!!! Greatly appreciated

Comment: Thank you!! Although Sunday should be weekday number 1, monday 2, tuesday 3, wednesday 4 etc throughout to Saturday which should be weekday number 7. Currently Sunday is weekday number 7 and saturday is weekday number 6.

Comment: Thanks, got everything working besides the first time, which I need to have it working. It is not working when I try on my own server, But the second and third etc times works fine. Can you make it work for the first time too, then I'll accept you right away :)

Comment: Hope you can help me with the last thing @Adrien Giboire

Comment: I have no time right now. And overall, it worked locally. I dont have any idea why it is not working for you yet. I think you should be able to find it out alone. If not, I will came back to help you when I will have some time.

Comment: There: http://jsfiddle.net/adrieng/VkYnQ/9/ The error was that I was trying to select the first select with the class `timeselect` when its class is `timeSelect`. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code:

use:

```
$('.timeSelect').on('change', function(){

    var ind = parseInt($(this).attr('id')) +2;
    var newVal = $(this).val().replace(':', '');
    $("input:checkbox").eq(ind).attr('name', 'copyTime[1]['+newVal+']');
    $("input:checkbox").eq(ind).next('span').html(newVal);

    console.log(ind);

});
```

But change:
 `clone()` with `.clone(true)` //ADDED

```
.attr('name', function() { // changing the name
                    return 'seats_timeclock[' + randnr + ']';
                }).attr('id', (parseInt($('select[name^=seats_timeclock]:last').attr('id')))+2) //ADDED
```

and add an id to select:

```
<td class="borderRight">
<select class="timeSelect" id="0" name="seats_timeclock[]">
```

This the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZadT/).